# Remove classList when changing route in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to remove the classList whenever the route changes in Next.js, I am trying this :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 const activatedLink = router.query.tags
 const classActivated = document.querySelector('.'+activatedLink)
 if(router.asPath) {
    classActivated?.classList.add('link-on')
 }
 else classActivated?.classList.remove('link-on')
}, [router.asPath])
```

Any idea how to remove the classList when the route changes ?

Comment: Instead, set the `className` to a value stored in state, then just update that state when the route changes.

Comment: @Lissy93 How to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const activatedLink = router.query.tags
   const classActivated = document.querySelector('.'+activatedLink)
   if(router.asPath === '/some/path') {
      classActivated?.classList.add('link-on')
   }else{
     classActivated?.classList.remove('link-on')
   }
},[router.asPath])
```